# Show Image at Top o ScrollView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to show an Image inside of a ScrollView, but the ScrollView always create an empty space at the top and bottom of the image.

```
 <ScrollView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        style={{flex: 1}}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          justifyContent: 'flex-start',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Image source={getImage(image)} style={styles.imageStyle} />
      </ScrollView>
```

Current styling:

```
imageStyle: {
   width: deviceWidth / 1.5,
   height: null,
   aspectRatio: 1,
   resizeMode: 'contain',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   alignItems: 'flex-start',
}
```

I also already tried to put a View inside the ScrollView an then the Image, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you're using aspect ratio.

Try :

```
     <ScrollView
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            }}>
            <Image source={getImage(image)} 
            resizeMode='cover'
            style={styles.imageStyle} />
          </ScrollView>

    imageStyle: {
       width: deviceWidth / 1.5,
       height: null,
       aspectRatio: 1:1,
       resizeMode: 'cover',
       justifyContent: 'flex-start',
       alignItems: 'flex-start',
alignSelf : 'flex-start',
    }
```